# Broadcasting to YouTube Live via RTMP using VLC from terminal

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, vlc, rtmp

When running:

```
cvlc -vvv 'Bootstrap Tutorial.mp4' --sout '#rtp{dst=rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2,name=pa1p-8c4m-zzvp-5j6t,mux=ts}'
```

I get [this debugging log](http://www.wepaste.com/vlcdebug/).

When additionally specifying the access method:

```
cvlc -vvv 'Bootstrap Tutorial.mp4' --sout '#std{access=rtmp,dst=rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pa1p-8c4m-zzvp-5j6t,mux=ts}'
```

I get [this debugging log](http://www.wepaste.com/vlcdebug2/).

How do I stream live video and audio to YouTube using VLC from terminal?

Resources I looked into:

1. https://blog.vucica.net/2015/08/streaming-to-youtube-live-with-vlc-and-ffmpeg.html
2. https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=130520&p=436913&hilit=rtmp+youtube#p436913
3. [Problems Starting VLC HTTP Stream with Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200617/problems-starting-vlc-http-stream-with-servlet)
4. https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=112221&p=380232&hilit=rtmp+youtube#p380232

Comment: at least comment first and let me know if you need more info here, before downvoting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i transmitted video to youtube live from terminal using vlc.

Following is the command:

```
cvlc  -vvv FILE016.MP4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Auto,width=1280,height=720,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=rtmp,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream-name}'
```

Note , youtube sometimes shows a message to use h264 as transcoder and ab to 128 when i tried to transcode video to flv on a low speed internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
VLC "${PATHTOFILE}" --sout '#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,acodec=mp3,samplerate=44100}:std{access=rtmp,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/'${STREAMID}
```

[Streaming to YouTube Live with VLC and FFMPEG](https://blog.vucica.net/2015/08/streaming-to-youtube-live-with-vlc-and-ffmpeg.html)

Comment: why should transcode mp4 to flv before transmission. i am transmitting in 720p

Comment: @devprashant Because _Youtube Live_ RTMPT server only accepts `flv` videos.